# Why does cross-multiplication not work when solving $ \frac{3x+1}{2x+4}<2x+1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I need to solve the following inequality:
$$ \frac{(3x+1)}{(2x+4)}<2x+1$$

Why can't I cross-multiply in this instance? I solved $3x+1 = (2x+1)(2x+4)$ which gave me the wrong answer (I solved for the roots of x and made a sign table)

The correct answer is as follows: $$ \frac{(3x+1)}{(2x+4)}-2x+1\frac{(2x+4)}{(2x+4)} = 
\frac{(3x+1)-(2x+4)(2x+1)}{(2x+4)}$$
where you can solve for the roots of x and make a sign table

I understand the answer, but don't know why my approach wouldn't give the same answer

Comment: When multiplying both sides of an inequality by a negative number, the inequality sign needs to be reversed

Comment: When you multiply by a negative, the inequality reverses. Did you check that $(2x + 4) > 0$, or invert the inequality when it was actually negative?

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. Seems like I made an error in my calculations. My method does indeed also give the correct answer.

Comment: One approach is to solve the equality if possible, in this case a quadratic. That avoids the difficulties of reversing the inequality.  Then the solution to the inequality will be either between the two roots or outside them (if two real roots, other cases handled easily enough).

Answer (score 0):

> Solve the inequality,$$\frac{(3x+1)}{(2x+4)}<2x+1$$

$\color{#024273}{\text{If, } 2x+4>0},$
$$(3x+1)<(2x+1)(2x+4)\\
{\Rightarrow3x+1<4x^2+10x+4\\
\Rightarrow4x^2+7x+3>0\\
\Rightarrow(x+1)(4x+3)>0 \\
\Rightarrow x\in(-\infty,-1)\cup(-\frac{3}4,\infty)\\}\\
\therefore x\in(-2,-1)\cup(-\frac{3}4,\infty) \quad [\because 2x+4>0\Rightarrow x>-2]$$

$\color{#024273}{\text{If, } 2x+4<0},$
$$(3x+1)>(2x+1)(2x+4)\\
{\Rightarrow3x+1>4x^2+10x+4\\
\Rightarrow4x^2+7x+3<0\\
\Rightarrow(x+1)(4x+3)<0 \\
\Rightarrow x\in(-1,-\frac{3}4)\\}\\
\therefore x\in \phi \quad [\because 2x+4<0\Rightarrow x<-2]$$

Hence, solution of the given inequality: $\boxed{x\in(-2,-1)\cup(-\frac{3}4,\infty)}$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{3x + 1}{2x + 4} < 2x + 1$
$(3x + 1) \cdot (2x + 4) < (2x + 1) \cdot (2x + 4)^2$ (*)
$6x^2 + 14x + 4 < (2x + 1) \cdot (4x^2 + 16x + 16)$
$6x^2 + 14x + 4 < 8x^3 + 36x^2 + 48x + 16$
$8x^3 + 30x^2 + 34x + 12 > 0$

(*) An inequality only holds when two parts are multiplied with the same **positive** number (a square is always positive).

(We already know that this is divisible by $2x + 4$)

$(2x + 4) \cdot (4x^2 + 7x + 3) > 0$
$(2x + 4) \cdot (4x + 3) \cdot (x + 1) > 0$
$(x + 2) \cdot (x + 1) \cdot (x + \frac{3}{4})> 0$

This is a typical third-degree equation, going from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ passing over three zeroes: $-2$, $-1$, and $-\frac{3}{4}$, so this is larger than zero between the first and the second zero and over the third one:

$$x \in [-2, -1] \cup ]-\frac{3}{4}, +\infty[$$